# Regular Expression for everything except all spaces and one special character

Tags: javascript, regex

Been at this several hours now and can't seem to get this seemingly easy regex working.  I've been successful excluding a single character with `^[^']+$` or just `[^']` and successful with all spaces with `[\\S]`, but I can't figure out how to combine them in a single expression.

I've tried many different combinations of:

```
^(?=[^'])[\\S]$
[\\S-[']]
```

The rules are quite simple - can't be all spaces and can't contain an apostrophe.  Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do the trick:

```
if (/'|^[ ]+$/.exec(str)) {
    // invalid...
}
```

Comment: Yep... worked like a charm.  Once again, I was over-thinking the solution.

Comment: @ChrisGessler, using test instead of exec will be more efficient.  Also this will miss tab characters and other white space characters.

Comment: @DanielGimenez - thanks for the heads up. I believe that's why I was using \S in the first place.

Comment: @DanielGimenez is right about the test method.But about the tabs... my initial answer was /'|^\s+$/ but then I noticed in the subject that Chris wrote "all spaces", that's why I changed it...

Comment: Yep. I didn't specify "whitespace", but I figured it out. It's the +$ and the fact that I'm negating now that did the trick (valid = !re.test(val));

Answer (score 2):

If you need to test for all spaces or an apostrophe then you may use the following:

```
if (/'|^\s+$/.test(str)) {
    // is invalid
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question Chris, but I think it would fail for the string "Chris's app", wouldn't it? it will not mark it as invalid.

Comment: Ah... true dat.  Can't be all spaces or contain an apostrophe.

Comment: @ChrisGessler Then the combined regex may be applied. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @vision, that's my answer.  You just inverted the alternation

Comment: @DanielGimenez False. This is my answer. Your first answer `/^\s+$|'/.test()` was wrong. Moreover I have seen your answer only when I have updated mine.

Comment: +1 for \s+ instead of [ ] - but essentially the same answer as @UdiCohen.  Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The following will be true if the entire string is whites pace, or there is any instance of an apostrophe.

```
if (/^\s+$|'/.test(s)) {
    // is invalid
}
```

The regex has an alternation between

- `^\s+$`:

  - `^`: Start Of String
  - `\s`: white space (1 or more times)
  - `$`: End of string
- `'`: the apostrophe character

If either of those two sequences is matched then the string is invalid.

Comment: Late, but yes - that appears to be the consensus.  +1 for providing an explanation.